# What format should i use to save JSON data in android

Tags: json

In what format should i save the JSON data i get from a server in order to populate them later in a ListView ?

Is a 2 dimensional array enough or is there a better solution?

Every JSON Object is like :

```
       {"id":"1","title":"London"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want to save the data? If it's in a preferences object then the JSON itself is a good option. Otherwise a `HashMap` would be appropriate, and much better than the two-dimensional array: faster, more logical, better suited.

Comment: HashMap is a pair of key and value. What if i want to save more than 2 fields?

Comment: In fact a HashMap is a set of key->value pairs, sorted by keys so it is very fast to look up a particular key: map.get(key).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`Arraylist<ClassName> jsondata=new ArrayList<ClassName>`

Here's an example:

```
public Class ClassName 
{

  string fname;
  string lname;

public void setfname(String fname)
{
  this.fname=fname;
}

public void setlname(String lname)
{
  this.lname=lname;
}

public String getlname(String lname)
{
  return lname;
}
public String getfname(String fname)
{
  return fname;
}
```

You can store it like this..